# BackboneJS: REST DELETE does not trigger on destroy()

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I am learning BackboneJS. With a REST backend I am trying to issue a HTTP DELETE in line: `this.at(0).destroy();` in the code below:

```js
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: 'Testing Just',
  },
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/todos/',
});

var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Task,
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/todos/'
});

var tasks = new Tasks();
tasks.fetch({
  context: tasks
}).done(function() {
  console.log("Tasks:" + this.length)
  console.log(this.at(0).get('name'));
  this.at(0).destroy();
  console.log("Tasks:" + this.length);
  console.log(this.at(0).get('name'));
});
```

The model is deleted from the collection but no REST DELETE occurs to the backend. The deletion on the REST backend works with 'localhost:8080/todos/0'.
Please advise what I am missing.

Comment: Do your models have ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The deletion on the REST backend works with 'localhost:8080/todos/0'

You probably thought that backbone issues requests based on the index of model in collection, which is not the case. The param which is appended to collection's url is the `id` of the model, and `id` is what backbone uses to check whether a model is persisted or not.

Your models probably doesn't have an [`id`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) attribute, or [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) set, so backbone thinks that model is not yet saved in persistence layer and there is no need to issue a DELETE request.

Comment: Thank you! Now I learned that without ID in model, backbone does not consider persistence and only optimistically deletes it from the collection.